# nested exceptions and primitive types

Tags: c++, c++11

Can I use `std::throw_with_nested` when my captured exception is of primitive type?

It is said, that the new type is derived from the captured exception and the new exception. But I can not derive from primitives types like `int`. Therefore I can not use nested exceptions with primitive types. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My copy of the standard says this:

> **18.8.6/7** *Throws*: if `U` is a non-union class type not derived from `nested_exception`, an exception of unspecified type that is publicly derived from both `U` and `nested_exception` and constructed from `std::forward<T>(t)`, otherwise `std::forward<T>(t)`.

So `throw_with_nested(42)` should `throw 42;`

Answer (score 1):

The standard says about `throw_with_nested(T && t)`, with `U = remove_reference<T>::type`:

> *Throws:*  if `U` is a non-union class type not derived from `nested_exception`, an exception of unspecified type that is publicly derived from both `U` and `nested_exception` and constructed from `std::forward<T>(t)`, otherwise `std::forward<T>(t)`.

The "otherwise" clause seems to say that if you don't have a class type, you just throw the original argument.

Answer (score 1):

The exception thrown is an unspecified type derived from the *new* exception and `std::nested_exception` (not the new and the captured). The `std::nested_exception` then contains a `std::exception_ptr` to the captured exception (obtained from `std::current_exception`).

So:

If the *new* exception is an `int` then you throw an `int` as other answers have stated.

If you *capture* an `int` then you throw (a type derived from) the new exception with the thrown `int` in the `std::nested_exception`.